# removing a watspp no of my old mob

Tags: notifications

Hi my old mobile died and i have watsapp on my new no and want to get rid of the old watsapp no contact in my new mob as no need to have it as new no.How do I delete it from my contacts on watsapp as no way i can.

Answer (score 0):

From the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/21119703):

> ## How do I delete my account?
>
> You can delete your account from within WhatsApp.
>
> WARNING! Deleting your account is an irreversible process, we cannot
> undo a deletion if you complete the process by accident.
>
> ## Deleting your account will do the following
>
> - Delete your account from WhatsApp.
> - Delete you from your friends' Select contact lists.
> - Delete you from all WhatsApp groups.
> - Erase your message history on your phone.
> - Delete your WhatsApp service payment information.
>
> ## To delete your WhatsApp account
>
> - Open WhatsApp.
> - Press the Menu Button > Settings > Account > Delete My
>   Account.
> - Enter your phone number in the full international format and
>   tap Delete My Account.
>
> Please note that we cannot delete your account
> for you at this time.

Comment: Pretty sure those instructions only apply if the phone with the account on it is still working/accessible.

Comment: yes @eldarerathis but in this case Diane can delete using a friends phone although there are some issues. Also if a cell phone number is no more used for 45 days it gets recycled on new device as info given on this link [link](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/24068052)